# Translating Navigation Globally

Tags: zend-framework2

I created an onBootstrap() function in my Module.php so I could globally set the translation text_domain on certain view helpers. I have all but one working how I'd like.

Here is the onBootstrap() function:

```
/**
 * @param MvcEvent $event
 */
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
{
    $sapi = php_sapi_name();

    if ($sapi != 'cli' || $sapi != 'cli-server') {
        $default = 'en-US';

        $application = $event->getApplication();

        /**
         * @var \Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService $session
         */
        $session = $application->getServiceManager()
                               ->get('Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService');

        if ($session->hasIdentity()) {
            $locale = $session->getIdentity()->locale;
        } else {
            $locale = $default;
        }

        $application->getServiceManager()
                    ->get('MvcTranslator')
                    ->setLocale($locale)
                    ->setFallbackLocale($default);

        AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator(
            $application->getServiceManager()
                        ->get('MvcTranslator')
        );

        AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslatorTextDomain('zend');

        /**
         * Translate Forms
         */
        $viewRenderer = $application
            ->getServiceManager()
            ->get('ViewRenderer');
        $application->getEventManager()
                    ->getSharedManager()
                    ->attach(
                        'Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController',
                        'dispatch',
                        function ($event) use
                        (
                            $viewRenderer
                        ) {
                            /**
                             * @var MvcEvent $event
                             */
                            $controller = $event->getTarget();

                            $controllerClass = get_class($controller);

                            $moduleNamespace = substr(
                                $controllerClass,
                                0,
                                strpos(
                                    $controllerClass,
                                    '\\'
                                )
                            );

                            $textDomain = strtolower($moduleNamespace);

                            $viewRenderer->plugin('translate')
                                         ->setTranslatorTextDomain($textDomain);

                            $viewRenderer->navigation('Zend\Navigation\Navigation')
                                         ->setTranslatorTextDomain('employee');

                            $viewRenderer->formLabel()
                                         ->setTranslatorTextDomain($textDomain);

                            $viewRenderer->formText()
                                         ->setTranslatorTextDomain($textDomain);

                            $viewRenderer->formPassword()
                                         ->setTranslatorTextDomain($textDomain);

                            $viewRenderer->formSubmit()
                                         ->setTranslatorTextDomain($textDomain);
                        },
                        100
                    );
    }
}
```

The part I am stuck on is:

```
$viewRenderer->navigation('Zend\Navigation\Navigation')
             ->setTranslatorTextDomain($textDomain);
```

I am not receiving any errors, but it's also not translating as expected. If I change `Zend\Navigation\Navigation` to something that does not exist, it errors as expected. So that tells me it's finding the key in the configuration.

I've also tried, but still doesn't translate as expected:

```
$viewRenderer->plugin('navigation')
             ->setTranslatorTextDomain($textDomain);
```

It works when I call this in my view:

```
$this->navigation('Zend\Navigation\Navigation')
     ->setTranslatorTextDomain('employee');
```

However the goal is to remove that line from all the views and set the text_domain in the onBootstrap() function.

You can see as a test, I've hardcoded the `$textdomain` as `employee` for now.

Any ideas what I can do?

Comment: First big mistake is that you are putting tons of code in your onBootstrap method. The Module.php is called on every HTTP request and it should be as thin as possible or you will get major performance issues. Consider using factories. Never leave your Module.php to do all the job!

Comment: I understand that, but your comment does not help in solving my problem.

Comment: Calling  
 `$sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
 $viewRenderer = $sm->get('ViewRenderer');
echo \Zend\Debug\Debug::dump(get_class_methods($viewRenderer), null, false);` shows that there isn't any navigation or  formText() methods. I know that these methods are only available as View Helpers

Comment: However it does work and the information is being translated properly. The only one in that entire function that does not translate yet is the navigation.